# Can't turn off SNI on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, http-headers, sni

When I go to: http://web-sniffer.net/ and check the headers of my site (https://www.example.org), I get a status code 200

But when I use the radio button HTTP/1.0 (without Host header), I get a status code 400 (Bad Request).

My apache log says "Hostname www.example.org provided via SNI, but no hostnmae provided in HTTP request"

I read that to make it work I need to turn off the directive "SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck" in my apache conf file.

I added this directive, but am still getting status code 400 when making a HTTP/1.0 (without Host Header)

For reference, this is my ports.conf file:

```
ServerName www.example.org

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 10.0.0.1:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

This is my default-ssl file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
    SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off


    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/public_html/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/public_html/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /media /home/ubuntu/public_html/media
<Directory /home/ubuntu/public_html/media >
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/public_html/apache.wsgi

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/crt/example_org.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/crt/server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/crt/ca.crt
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
# MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell from looking at the [Apache source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/modules/ssl/ssl_engine_kernel.c), you can't do that with *any* Apache configuration option. You [MUST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119) send a Host: header matching what was sent via SNI for Apache to accept it.

[RFC 6066 section 11.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-11.1) specifies that web servers [MUST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119) check that the Host: header and host name sent via SNI match.

As a practical matter, any software speaking HTTP that was produced in the last 15 years or so should be sending the Host: header with every request. If you actually have something that isn't, it's either too ancient to still be on the Internet, or broken.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this test (site) is broken. If you use HTTP/1.0 with no host header it is unlikely you ever sent a SNI extension. I dont think you need to "fix" your site to support this.